# AWS Lambda gets the content of a private wiki in Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, wiki

I'm trying to access a private wiki in azure (I'm admin in the project) but using the a lambda in AWS.

```
import requests
import base64

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Replace with your own Azure DevOps organization name
    organization_name = "name of the organization"
    # Replace with the project name that contains the wiki
    project_name = "project name"
    # Replace with the name of the wiki
    wiki_name = "wiki name"
    # Replace with the version of the wiki to retrieve
    wiki_version = "1234"
    # Replace with your own personal access token (PAT)
    personal_access_token = "my pat"

    # Build the URL to retrieve the wiki content
    url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization_name}/{project_name}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki_name}/{wiki_version}/content?api-version=7.0"

    # Set the authorization header with the base64-encoded PAT
    auth_header = f"Basic {base64.b64encode(f'{personal_access_token}'.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')}"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": auth_header,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
    # Make the request to retrieve the wiki content
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # Return the response if successful, otherwise return an error message
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
```

My lambda has a security group allowing all inbound and outbound, and public subnet.
Also lambda has a very permisive role lol

But I always get a

"[ERROR] ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dev.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:xxxxx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f405ba34790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))"

Not sure if the issue is the lambda or in azure.

I already tried changing the permissions and changing the role of aws lamdba.
Also I got another PAT with all permissions allowed.

Comment: Does your subnet have a route to a NAT gateway? Is it a private subnet?

Comment: I also tried changing the timeout.

Comment: Yes, I made sure to check. It is a public subnet,  theres a destination "0.0.0.0/0" and a target of the ID of my NAT gateway.

Comment: If you try to load just `https://checkip.amazonaws.com`, does it work?

Comment: I get "Task timed out after 183.10 seconds" but if I remove the VPC I get the 'OK' response.

Comment: Yes, because your VPC setup does not work. Your lambda needs to be in a subnet with a route to a NAT in a public subnet with a route to an IGW.

Comment: If there a particular reason why you want to have the AWS Lambda function connected to the VPC? If not, then don't connect it and things would appear to be fine.